# Help with PrevGroupVal to display analytical trend data

Tags: reporting, analytics

I need to create a report to view the growth of subscribers to specific programs. I created a matrix report with row groupings on Program and column Grouping on Subscription Date (Calendar Month).

I created a formula - SubscriptionCnt:SUM+
PREVGROUPVAL(SubscriptonCnt:SUM, Subscription_Date,1) but this considers only the previous value. It doesn't give me the total of all the previous subscriptions. I tried editing it to

SubscriptionCnt:SUM+
PREVGROUPVAL(SubscriptonCnt:SUM, Subscription_Date,1) + PREVGROUPVAL(SubscriptonCnt:SUM, Subscription_Date,2) ... and so on. This neither works. In this case it doesn't display the values for first two columns and displays for the third by counting all the previous.

Can someone help me correct the formula so I can display the trend of growth in an incremental way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like a running total/cumulative report is buildable yet, there is an idea out on the [IdeaExchange](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrZV), however, you could add a Cumulative Line Chart to show the trend.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the availability of previous group values.

PREVGROUPVAL(AMOUNT:SUM, Opportunity.Femma_ClosingPhase__c)

+
IF(PREVGROUPVAL(AMOUNT:SUM, Opportunity.Femma_ClosingPhase__c, 2) > 0,PREVGROUPVAL(AMOUNT:SUM, Opportunity.Femma_ClosingPhase__c, 2) ,0)
+

IF(PREVGROUPVAL(AMOUNT:SUM, Opportunity.Femma_ClosingPhase__c, 3) > 0,PREVGROUPVAL(AMOUNT:SUM, Opportunity.Femma_ClosingPhase__c, 3) ,0)

+AMOUNT:SUM

Comment: I coincidentally ran into your answer. There's a slightly nicer way to do this, using the nullvalue frunction: NULLVALUE(PREVGROUPVAL(AMOUNT:SUM, Opportunity.Femma_ClosingPhase__c))

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jan for the answer.  This worked for me.  I did change the first line to the following so that my first group would have a value too

PREVGROUPVAL(AMOUNT:SUM, Opportunity.Femma_ClosingPhase__c)

to

If (PREVGROUPVAL(AMOUNT:SUM, Opportunity.Femma_ClosingPhase__c) > 0, PREVGROUPVAL(AMOUNT:SUM, Opportunity.Femma_ClosingPhase__c) ,0)

Comment: I coincidentally ran into your answer. There's a slightly nicer way to do this, using the nullvalue frunction: NULLVALUE(PREVGROUPVAL(AMOUNT:SUM, Opportunity.Femma_ClosingPhase__c))